# How do I disable the Swype button I see in the virtual keyboard?

Tags: swype

On my Samsung Galaxy Next, I enabled the Swype mode, but I don't find anymore where I enabled it, and where I can disable it.
I tried with the "Language and keyboard" settings, but I find only the Swype settings, under "Text settings."

How do I disable the Swype mode, and avoid the Swype button appear in the virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to change the input method by long pressing on a text box > Input Method.  The menu should give you a list of input methods, select the one that is not Swype.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday and couldnt figure out how to turn it off! The first answer up there ^^worked for me...I went into a text ready to answer it held my finger on the area you text and it bought up options Swype and samsung keyborad.

Comment: The method is not very intuitive. But that's the way. Long tap on message text box (or whats app chat etc.). There u find the "input method".

Answer (score 0):

From the Home screen, press the menu button and go to Language Settings, where you'll be able to select the default keyboard.

You can also change the keyboard by long pressing a text box.

Comment: In the "Language and keyboard" settings, there are just the settings to change the language, and the settings for the Swype and the keypad; none of them allow to select the default keyboard.